# How to create Map between two tables using where statement?

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, asp.net-core

I have Doctor and Appointment tables.On my DTO I have DoctorName field and I want to bring that name from doctor table by AutoMapper.I tried to Map like below on AutoMapperProfile but it says `cannot convert from 'bool' to 'System.Func<<char,bool>`. Both values are string that I want to map so doesnt make sense.Here my Models,DTO and CreateMap below.

**Doctor**

```
public class Doctor
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    }
```

**Appointment**

```
   public class Appointment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime AppointmentDate { get; set; }
        public int DoctorId { get; set; }
        public Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
        public int? PatientId { get; set; }
        public Patient Patient { get; set; }
    }
```

**AutoMapperProfile**

```
      CreateMap<Appointment, AvilableAppointmentDto>()
                    .ForMember(dep => dep.DoctorName, 
opt => opt.MapFrom(src => 
src.Doctor.Name.Where(src.DoctorId==src.Doctor.Id)));
```

**DTO**

```
   public class AvilableAppointmentDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime AppointmentDate { get; set; }
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }        
    public string DoctorName { get; set; }

}
```

**UPDATE(Solution)**
Dto should be mapped as IENumerable.Like below

```
    var returnAppointments = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<AvilableAppointmentDto>>(availableAppointments);
```

Comment: can you please try this?
CreateMap<Appointment, AvilableAppointmentDto>()
                    .ForMember(dep => dep.DoctorName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Doctor.Name));

Comment: I've tried that one already.Gives me AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. error after request

Answer (score 0):

Below thing works for me

Mapping:

```
CreateMap<Appointment, AvilableAppointmentDto>(MemberList.Destination)
                    .ForMember(dep => dep.DoctorName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Doctor.Name));
```

Entity Classes:

```
public class Doctor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
}

public class Appointment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime AppointmentDate { get; set; }
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }
    public Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
    public int? PatientId { get; set; }
}

public class AvilableAppointmentDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime AppointmentDate { get; set; }
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }
    public string DoctorName { get; set; }

}
```

controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get([FromServices] IMapper mapper)
    {
        Appointment ap = new Appointment()
        {
            AppointmentDate = DateTime.Now,
            DoctorId = 1,
            Id = 2,
            PatientId = 3,
            Doctor = new Doctor()
            {
                Id = 1,
                DepartmentId = 2,
                Name = "Ajay",
                Title = "Mr"
            }
        };

        var x = mapper.Map<AvilableAppointmentDto>(ap);

        return Ok(x);
    }
```

startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {            
        var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
        {
            mc.AddProfile<MappingProfile>();
        });

        var mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();

        services.AddSingleton(mapper);
    }
```

Package ref.

```
<PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0" />
```

Comment: Are you sure?Controller returns only string array not the DTO you mapped

Comment: X in the method contains the actual dto after mapping. Return of string array is just a default template that I didn't remove. I am using .net core web api for this sample.

Comment: Yeah I got it but you should have returned x I mean not that array

Comment: I solved the problem and edited my answer you can check if you want